# Query to find foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a database where I need to drop some foreign keys, but I don't know beforehand whether the foreign keys still exist.

I've found some stored procedures (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,218825,247526) that does the trick, but I don't want to create a stored procedure for this.

I've tried to use the query inside the stored procedure, but I get an error using "IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM etc.. etc...

Can I only use `IF EXISTS` in stored procedures?

---

right now, the only thing I can run is

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
AND information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema'
AND information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME = 'mytable';
```

and I've tried this too

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = parm_key_name) THEN
(...) do something (...)
END IF;
```

but I get a `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF' at line 1`

I've looked for examples in forums with simple queries and I can't make sense of why this isn't working.

NOTE: Edit to correct broken link

Comment: So what does your query look like?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "drop foreign keys"?

Comment: @ gview something like ALTER TABLE `table` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk` ;

Answer (score 10):

You need to connect to the Information scheme and you can find all the information about the primary key and foreign keys in this table

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T;`

you need to be a `ROOT` user to access the `information_schema`.

USING this table you can find the table, db and whether it has foreign key.

Hope this helps if you dont wanna use `IF EXIST` and Stored Procedure. But I am Sure you can use `IF EXIST` can be used for non stored procedure queries....

Comment: "[Y]ou need to be a ROOT user to access the information_schema." Where did you find this information?

Comment: I think it is more accurate to say that a user can only view the part of the information schema that they have permissions on. If a user is created with `GRANT ALL` then they can see the permissions on that table.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't You use the table "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" to this?

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the Information scheme and you can find all the information about the primary key and foreign keys in this table

```
 select
        concat(table_name, '.', column_name) as 'foreign key',  
        concat(referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name) as 'references'
    from
        information_schema.key_column_usage
    where
        referenced_table_name is not null;
```

> HELP: see this link [list-foreign-keys-in-mysql](http://www.binarytides.com/list-foreign-keys-in-mysql/)