# cannot drop a foreign key in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

It's a common example between Persons and Orders. I just copied it from Internet as a test.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) );

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(ID)
);
```

Till now it's all successful. But how can I drop the Foreign Key PersonID?

I tried this.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
DROP FOREIGN KEY PersonID;
```

MySQL said:

> 1091 - Can't DROP 'PersonID'; check that column/key exists

Comment: The foreign key name you are trying to drop doesn't exist.  You need to find it with a query.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765820/query-to-find-foreign-keys.  Edit:  if you don't name the constraint, it's usually named "table_name.column_name", so in your case, "Orders.PersonID".

Comment: "PersonID" is the name of the field on which the key applies, but is not (necessarily) the name of the key itself. As T Gray says, if you don't know the name of the key you'll have to query for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to drop the foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632587/unable-to-drop-the-foreign-key)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify the name of the constraint using the statement:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Orders'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'PersonID';
```

Use the result from `CONSTRAINT_NAME` in your `ALTER TABLE` statement. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
DROP FOREIGN KEY `myconstraint`;
```

Answer derived from the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-keys-dropping)

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete constraint and also the key. First find the constraint by doing the following

1) SHOW CREATE table Orders;

[image: result will be something like this]

pick up value of CONSTRAINT.. in this screenshot 'fk_dayBreakUp_timetable'

2) ALTER TABLE Orders DROP foreign key << constraint_name >>

here you would do

3) ALTER TABLE Orders DROP key << column name >>

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: This will work provided the foreign key was named.  In his case, it was not, so the show create won't help.  Without a name, the constraint is defaulted to "table.column".  It's better to get the constraint as named from the dictionary, IMO.